# How does one splice a list and create a new list with the spliced section?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

Here is an example.

The file has a string: `4;4;4;8;4;4;4;9;9;4;4`.

I would like it to output:

```
4;4;4
8
4;4;4
9
9
4;4
```

In this example the limit determining when to splice would be any number greater than 4. I have tried looking at the python libraries and other questions here.  My guesses have involved the following:

```
listA = [] 
listB = []
for i in line:
    listA.append(i)

for item in listA:
    if int(item) > 4:
         listB.append(item)
    else:
         item = item

print(listA)
print(listB)
```

Is there a more efficient and faster way?  I am sure there is but I am not that experienced in python and would appreciate the help!

Comment: I will be doing this for thousands of lines in a file, so a loop generating lists would also be great!

Comment: Thanks Martijn for the formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`itertools.groupby`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby

for key, group in groupby(line.split(';'), key=lambda i: int(i) > 4):
    if key:
        for i in group:
            print(i)
    else:
        print(';'.join(group))
```

Demo:

```
>>> for key, group in groupby(line.split(';'), key=lambda i: int(i) > 4):
...     if key:
...         for i in group:
...             print(i)
...     else:
...         print(';'.join(group))
... 
4;4;4
8
4;4;4
9
9
4;4
```

The `groupby` utility function groups sequences by a key; here by wether or not the values are greater than 4 or not; each iteration gives us a sequence of values that are one or the other  If the values in the current group *are* indeed greater we print them on seperate lines, otherwise they are joined again into one string with semicolons.

Comment: When I run this with an example `line = 4;4;4;5;4;4` it says that there is a Type_error where the 'int' object is not iterable.  When I do the same thing with `line = '4;4;4;5;4;4'` it says there is an invalid literal for int() base 10.  I think this refers to the ";".  Let me know what you think.  Thanks @Martijn Pieters

Comment: Also... I am a little confused as to what the above answer really means.  An explanation would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Note that this retains `9;9` while the OP's example shows they're expecting the `9`'s as separate groups...

Comment: I would appreciate it if the `9`'s were separate groups.

Comment: Why are the `9`s separate but not the last two `4`s?

Comment: The last two `4`'s both are values less than the 5.  I am looking at gap sizes in protein sequences and would like to conserve the clusters where the gap size, the numbers, are less than a certain value.

Comment: apologies all, fixing things in between.

Comment: Thank you so much Martijn Pieters!  I really appreciate everything! @MartijnPieters